# Non-Divisible Subset - Hackerrank

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am trying to solve the Non-Divisible Subset problem from Hackerrank (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/non-divisible-subset). I am trying to use the idea that if the sum of a and b is divisible by k, then a%k+b%k = k, however, it's not working very well. 
Here is what I've written so far:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
   int n;
   int k;
   cin >> n;
   cin >> k;
    int j;
   vector<int>numbers;
   vector<int>remainders;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       int z;
       cin >> z;
       numbers.push_back(z);
   }
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++) {
      j = *it % k;
      remainders.push_back(j);
    }

    for(vector<int>::iterator it2 = remainders.begin(); it2 != remainders.end(); it2++) {
        int remainderCount = 0;
        int otherRemainderCount = 0;
        otherRemainderCount = std::count(remainders.begin(), remainders.end(), k-*it2);
        remainderCount = std::count(remainders.begin(), remainders.end(), *it2);
        if (remainderCount > otherRemainderCount) {
            theChosenOne = *it2;
        } else if (otherRemainderCount > remainderCount) {
            theChosenOne = k-*it2;
        }
       cout << theChosenOne << endl;
    }

  return 0;
    }
```

I created a vector for the remainders and I am using the std::cout function to find out which remainder appears more in the vector. If K would be 5, *it2 = 4, and k-*it2 = 1. If *it2 appears more times, then I would choose *it2. Otherwise, I would choose k-*it2.

Comment: Did you already inspect your program with the debugger?

Comment: I really dislike HackerRank and similar.  It (they) encourages "cute" throwaway code that is not maintainable.

Comment: @MirunaCamelia _"Yeah, it doesn't work."_ That's actually too vague. Please exactly descrube in your question how it _didn't work_ and tell us what you were observing when you stepped through your code with the debugger.

Comment: @MartinBonner What alternative would you recommend?

Comment: @0x499602D2: A proper course or book.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks to be on the right track, but there is some change that is needed.

*You basically need to hash the numbers in the array to proper location.*

Have an array `rem[k]` initialised to 0.

Iterate over the `n` numbers in the array, and do the following:

```
rem[array[i]%k]++;
```

Now you have to deal with only the `rem[]` array, to find the maximum subset. The `rem` array has size of maximum `k<=100`. Make use of the small size of `rem[]` array to find the solution efficiently.

**Edit:** Adding the code for you.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
   int n,i,k;
   cin>>n>>k;
   int arr[n];
   int rem[k]={0};
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       cin>>arr[i];    
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       rem[arr[i]%k]++;
   }
   int count = 0;
   for(i=1;i<=k/2;i++)
   {
       count = count + max(rem[i],rem[k-i]);
   }
   count = count + (rem[0]>0?1:0);
   if(k%2==0)
   {
     count = count - rem[k/2];
     if(rem[k/2]>0)
        count = count + 1;
   }
   cout<<count;
   return 0;
}
```

*After you have found out the contents of the `rem[]` array, its time to find the maximum subset. If you select `rem[1]` then you cannot select `rem[k-1]` as any two numbers, one from `rem[1]` and another from `rem[k-1]` can be summed together which will be divisible by `k` that we don't want. So we find whichever is maximum out of `rem[i]` and `rem[k-i]` and add it to the count*

My code uses the above logic..

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Why is it until k/2 in for(i=1;i<=k/2;i++)?

Comment: I have already explained the reason in the explanation. Say `k=7`, I am trying to find `max` between rem[1] and rem[6], rem[2] and rem[5], rem[3] and rem[4]. For that, I only need to write a loop till `k/2`.

Comment: This algorithm doesnt give the correct answer .For example for input
10 4  and set 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
it will give answer 3 but the correct is 5

Comment: @tzanou My code is giving answer as 5. Please test correctly before commenting!! Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    vector <int> a(n);
    vector <int> r(k,0);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        cin>>a[i];
        r[a[i]%k]++;
    }
    int ctr=min(1,r[0]);
    for(int a=1;a<(k/2+1);a++)
    {
        if(a!=k-a)
            ctr+=max(r[a],r[k-a]);
    }

    if(k%2==0&&r[k/2]!=0)
        ctr++;
    cout<<ctr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant explanation instead of just code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int a, int b) { return a < b ? a : b; }

int max(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }

int main() {
int n, k, a, total = 0;
scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
int mods[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
mods[i] = 0;
while (n--) {
scanf("%d", &a);
mods[a % k]++;
}
// can only have 1 value congruent to 0 mod k
total += min(1, mods[0]);
// if even, can only have 1 value congruent to k/2 mod k
if (k % 2 == 0)
total += min(1, mods[k / 2]);
// for all others, pick max of those k and n-k mod k
for (int d = 1; d < (k + 1) / 2; d++) { // for all others,
total += max(mods[d], mods[k - d]);
}
printf("%d", total);
return 0;
}
```